# Why did mdadm disable a disk on my raid array?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

In syslog I see:

```
Jun  3 15:07:12 storage kernel: [36518.430143] md/raid1:md0: Disk failure on sdd1, disabling device.
Jun  3 15:07:12 storage kernel: [36518.430143] md/raid1:md0: Operation continuing on 1 devices.
```

This was a disk failure in one of 2 raid1 arrays. Last week I had 2 disk failures at the same time, one on each array. I suspect this might not be a problem with the disks.

I added the drives again and everything seams to be working fine for now.

How can I find out why linux disabled my devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step to diagnosing this would be to run S.M.A.R.T tests on the disk - something like

```
sudo smartctl -A /dev/sdX
```

To see what it self reports.  You might also want to do long disk tests and see what they say - although probably not much.

It might also be worth advising what kind of disks you are using.  A while back I was using 2 regular disks which seemed to have similar problems - I can't recall the exact symptoms or messages but eventually chalked this down to them not being compatible with RAID.  There are differences between standard desktop drives and RAID/Enterprise class drives with respect of handling RAID - even MDADM software RAID.